# REST API for internal consumption and authentication

Tags: rest, authentication

When I use public APIs from web applications, I am provided with an API key that I use inside my client, as a string.

Now suppose I design a REST API for internal consumption. Let's say for a mobile app eshop. The user of the eshop logs in with a username and a password.

Does that mean that my client won't use API key authentication but username and password? I also see OAuth2 a lot in REST APIs, which also seems like a key-oriented authentication. Are they just different types, all valid ones? The API keys are usually issued for developers though, could that work with customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could work and it's also what you will be seeing in many cases. You login with username and password (POST request) and the server returns you an authentication token which you store in a Cookie through response headers. When user specific information is being required you would be using that token to authenticate, similar to how OAuth2 and dev keys work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding on your question -

There are methods or way on how you can authenticate your api. Some of the common ones are through Oauth, Token authentication and Basic auth (username and password).

You can read some of the concepts here - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Hope this helps